# Getting variable from the Url

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that retrieves information that a user clicks on in a database table.The user can select any one of ten rows that becomes highlighted when mouseover and when the user clicks the highlighted row the function retrieves it and puts it into a textbox. Then if the user submits this request for purchase I want to echo the textbox on the next page which is an order form.

The code below works well up until I try to retrieve the information from the url. I can see that it is passed in the url to the next page but after trying for two days I have not been able to retrieve it. I don't know where to go from here. Can someone look at this and see if I have not coded properly or done something wrong.
I have copied down the code that applies...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table tr").click(function(){
       $("#txttread").val($.map($(this).children('td:not(:eq(7))'), function (item) { return $(item).text() }).join(' - '));
  });
});


$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.pickme tr').not(':first').hover(
        function() { $(this).addClass('highlight'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('highlight'); }
    ).click( function() {
        $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected').find('input').attr('checked','checked');
    });
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Order.html" method="GET" name="myform2" />



<div>
<div style="text-align:left height:250px;">
<DIV STYLE="font-family: Arial Black;
color: black; font-size: 20pt;">

Select from inventory below:<br/><input type="text" style="width:500px; height:35px;" rows="1" STYLE="font-family: Arial Black;
color: red; font-size: 20pt;" name="txttread" id="txttread" DISABLED /></div></div></div>
<div>
<div style="text-align:center;">



<br/><input type="button" button id="getone" name="getone" value="Submit your request for purchase" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://localhost/order.html?txttread='+ ( $('#txttread').val() )"><br/><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

The url on the next page is....

```
    http://localhost/order.html?txttread=Firestone - All Season - FR-710 - 225/60/16 - 4 - 3 - 60.00
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question completely, but consider this:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/order.html?txttread='+ ( $('#txttread').val() )
```

You should apply proper escaping when you pass parameters:

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost/order.html?txttread=' + encodeURIComponent( $('#txttread').val() );
```

To access the value of `txttread` from an HTML page:

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

As found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1338292

Comment: I still cannot echo out any information from the url on the order form.

Comment: @Urob are you trying to access the `txttread` from HTML or PHP btw?

Comment: Thanks Jack sorry for the time delay as I am called away often. I am very new at coding in html, jquery, and php. I can do some of the simple stuff but as I progress I do get confused on quite a few issues. It is a html page that I am trying to access the txttread. How do I echo it out on the page?

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with the URL not being encoded correctly. On that last line where you append the `$('#txttread').val()`, you should wrap it with `encodeURIComponent()`:

```
<input type="button" 
       button id="getone" 
       name="getone" 
       value="Submit your request for purchase" 
       onclick="window.location.href = 'http://localhost/order.html?txttread=' + encodeURIComponent($('#txttread').val());">
```